# Unable to find CMake in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I need to add C/C++ code in my Android program for which I needed LLDB, CMake, and NDK. I found LLDB and NDK in SDK manager, but CMake is missing from there. I tried manually downloading it from the CMake official site and found out that for Android we need SDK customized CMake.

[image]

As you can see there is no option such as CMake.

Where do I find a version of CMake for Android?

I have tried CMake from the website and one I found in ndk-bundle/build folder, but both are giving the same error as below. What can be made out of it and how can the issue be solved?

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing 'C:\Users\amishr33\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HC:\Users\amishr33\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\jni -BC:\Users\amishr33\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\amishr33\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\amishr33\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\amishr33\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\amishr33\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=15 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static}
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja
Generators
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
                                 2003 project files.
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
Error:executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\amishr33\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\jni\CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Which version of Android studio are u using? 
Try to **update to the lastest**, I tried to update my android Studio to 2.2.3 and inside Android SDK --> SDK Tools it appears to me as u can see here: [screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/vfsobwbtf/)
I hope i helped u m8 :D
Sorry for answering a bit late :(

Comment: Are you using 32 bit windows ? Android Studio Cmake only works on 64 bit machines. That's why you could not find Cmake in the SDK manager .

Comment: make sure you are using 64 bit Android Studio! See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912919/android-studio-2-3-i-got-failed-to-find-cmake-install-cmake-and-sync-project/47569954#47569954

Comment: have u solved the problem?

Comment: you can install it in sdk manager tools, but first you must close your project

Comment: I updated the version Android studio..and found cmake in SDK tools @MNFS

Comment: Why do all these answers have so many upvotes?

Comment: The question clearly says the problem is Cmake is not present in the list, and non of thew answers give a solution to this problem, or say it is happening

Answer (score 195):

- Open **SDK Manager**
- Switch to the **SDK Tools** tab
- Install **CMake**

[image: Example Image]

Comment: i think the question is about no CMake in SDK Tools

Comment: Why is this in "Appearance & Behavior"?

Comment: For anyone who got here because they did not have a particular version of CMake (for me it was `CMake '3.10.2' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.` ) Click the "Show Package Details" box in bottom right to allow you to download the particular version.

Answer (score 33):

If you do the following you may get CMake without any problems:

1. Open the Settings (Android Studio);
2. Search by "Android SDK";
3. On the right side, go to the "SDK Tools" pallet|tab;
4. Check the "CMake" item on the list;
5. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> button;
6. Now, just wait the next century while Gradle builds, =D .

Comment: I think the issue is that no CMake is showing on the menu

Comment: This answer was helpful, but the last piece of it is, if you want to install a SPECIFIC version of CMAKE, make sure to select "Show Package Details" in the bottom right corner

Answer (score 16):

1. Check in your build.gradle file for your App's module

   ```
   externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           path "CMakeLists.txt"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Remove the `cmake` section
3. Re-synchronise the project:
   go to menu Build -> Refersh Lined C++ Projects
4. Right-click on the module, such as the app module, select "Link C++ Project with Gradle" from the menu.
5. You should see a dialog similar to the one shown in below figure.

   [image]
6. Click OK.

Comment: There in no item `Refersh Lined C++ Projects` in as3 menu

Comment: Thank you but I have a problem in cMakeList.txt set_target_properties error can you please help me

Comment: Thank you so much, it saved my lots of time

Answer (score 11):

- Go to Android SDK manager
- Select Android SDK Tools
- Find CMake and click <kbd>Apply</kbd> to download.
- Later click <kbd>OK</kbd> 
  [image: Instructions]

Comment: Thanks Girish. This is the best way to fix it and it worked for me!!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I'm not sure if my solution will be relevant, I will leave it here anyways

go to `/Users/yournamehere/Library/Android/sdk/ndk` I found the version `21.4.7075529` and deleted it, and then downloaded the same version again using android studio from `configuration > Preferences` and follow the steps in the attached image[image]

Answer (score 4):

For me the error was:

> CMake '3.10.2' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property

I solved it by adding `+` to CMake version.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.10.2+' // added plus after version
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Android Studio 3.0), there was no CMake in the "SDK Tools" tab in "Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK" options. However I noticed that in the "SDK Update sites" tab, there are only two entries, one of which (Android Repository    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml) had a red mark in the "enabled" column. It read "error 407" on mouseover, which is a proxy authentication error. I had the correct proxy settings (test connection worked fine with the same repository URL), so this was very strange. Restarting android studio didn't help. So I added a new entry with the same repository and this time it worked fine and CMake appeared in the other tab. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

**place path of the module where your cmake is exist**

if your cmake exist in app main

```
 externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                        path "CMakeLists.txt"
                      }
            }
```

if your cmake exist in any module

```
  externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    path file('../modulelib/CMakeLists.txt')
                }
            }
```

where "modulelib" is your library module folder name

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing `CMake path` worked :

```
externalNativeBuild {
    /*
      cmake {
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
      }
    */

    cmake {
        path 'src/main/jni/opus/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install it in the SDK Manager Tools, but first you must close your opened project. Use configuration on start menu.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Open Android Studio
2. Hover over your toolbar until you find *SDK Manager*, as in the image above
3. Click on *SDK Manager*
4. In *Default Preferences*, go to *Appearance and Behavior*
5. Now select *System Settings*
6. Now select *Android SDK*
7. Click on *SDK Tools*
8. Check on *CMake*

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using a 64-bit version of Android Studio. In Android Studio 32 bit, CMake will not appear in SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

For me what solved as taking off the "version" option in my gradle

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            //version was here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, worked for me, since my cmake was more recent than the one asked for.  My up vote makes it 0 I guess :), but for Linux Mint folks, this answer is good.  You'll also need to install ninja-build.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I think this site explains what you need:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-cmake/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Remember to check the "What you'll need"

## Update:

NDK: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
source: https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

CMake: https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.1-win64-x64.zip
source: https://cmake.org/

LLDB (Just for Debian systems): http://apt.llvm.org/
source: http://lldb.llvm.org/download.html

Once you download these files, copy to your SDK folder (normally in: "C:\android-sdk\") 
You can localize the folder here:

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location

Then you can continue with the previous guide after the downloads :)

Comment: but it doesn't tell how/where to get CMake for android studio.

Comment: You are searching the "download" section?

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
If u have any problem, make me know it and I'll be happy to help u :D

Comment: download section asks to open SDK manager and download CMake from their... but there is no CMake option in SDK manager.

Comment: @ashishmishra Check the update of the answer, i think that's what u need.

Comment: I have already tried that part, downloading cmake manually from its website and saving it in sdk folder. but it does not work. I n my research on this issue i found that SDK uses a specifically customised CMake for android, I am trying to find that version of CMake.

Answer (score 0):

For me, mac OS Android studio. in File->Project Structure-> Project, I changed Gradle version to 4.4 and Android plugin version to 3.1.0, then it gets good.

Plus, you can also change Android plugin version in gradle-> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Android Studio 4.2 C15 using SDK 30 in tandem with OpenCV 4 and Ninja, and in my case changing the CMake path like below worked:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    /*
      cmake {
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
      }
    */

    cmake {
         path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}
```