# Why cmake is missing in my SDK manager?

Tags: android, cmake

I am trying in android studio 2.2.3 to build c++ code with cmake.
But it report the following error:

> Error:Failed to find CMake. Install from Android Studio under
>   File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK
>   Tools/CMake. Expected CMake executable at
>   /Users/zhaoliang/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/bin/cmake.

I searched here and official site, which said we can install via SDK manager but there is no cmake in android studio->tools->SDK manager->SDK tools.

And I am using macbook pro not 32bit OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find CMake in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218241/unable-to-find-cmake-in-android-studio)