# Android Studio 2.3. I got Failed to find Cmake. Install CMake and sync project

Tags: android, android-ndk

My Android Studio versions is 2.3.

I created new project and i checked "include C++" because I want to do NDK but..

[image]

I got error that Failed to find Cmake, Install Cmake and sync project.

I click this 10 times

but nothing happened.

I search SDK manager to install cmake but I can't see word "cmake" anywhere

[image]

What can I to do?

Comment: please see this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41218241/794088

Comment: thanks you very much!!!! :)))

Comment: @sangho Which solution worked?

Comment: @Antonio nothing all.. I don't find cmake in SDK manager.

Comment: @sangho Do you have [cmake](https://cmake.org/download/#latest) installed?

Comment: @Antonio I could not install cmake..

Comment: What's your operating system? Why you cannot install cmake from the installer you download from cmake website?

Comment: @Antonio Windows 7.   I searched how to Cmake installation using googleing. and then I downloaded cmake from cmake web site.   and I installed a cmake. but.. I couldn't connect between Android Studio and Cmake. Android Studio still show me "Install Cmake" .. I give up the installation. T_T ..

Comment: Maybe it could be enough to add the path to cmake.exe to your path variable once installed. But indeed, the SDK Tools don't seem to support that feature anymore.

Comment: @Antonio Thank you for your consideration ^_^. I think so too.

Comment: did @Antonio's comment help? If they did, one of you should put it as an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I think the conclusion was that there's no installation of CMake anymore from the SDK Manager. This doesn't really offer a solution to OP problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Open the SDK tools settings while you're connected to the Internet. While opening this setting android studio tries to update or rather refresh available tools...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
The solution:
File->Settings->Appearance&Behavior->System settings->Android SDK, and then go to the tab "SDK Tools". You can install CMake there and everything else you want.

Comment: There is no "Android SDK" option under system settings anymore. They can shuffle GUI stuff around, but won't fix this basic out-of-the box functionality. Back to VisualStudio and Xamarin it is then. Waste of time.

Comment: But does Xamarin work really as well as Android Studio? I don't mean setting up the studio, but coding. I tried to use it, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using 64 bit version of Android Studio. In Android Studio 32 bit, cmake will not appear in sdk manager!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is vague.  I am going to provide some clarification.  First you have to download cmake.  Create a file inside your android studio SDK folder called CMake.  Install Cmake to this location.  then start android studio in administrator mode and all should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use studio64.exe to open the project

Answer (score -3):

change 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS..Then reinstall Android Studio..

Issue solved.