# cmake is found to install from sdk Tools

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio

I have installed android studio and getting gradle sync failed error: install cmake and sync project is shown is messsage but when i am clicking it nothing happend.

in event log error is Showing as:
Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake.
Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake. Expected CMake executable a C:\Users\Disz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe.
Consult IDE log for more details...

No cmake is found to install from sdk Tools
plz Help...I am new to android...

and i have reinstalled the android studio but problem is same again...

Answer (score 0):

Potential duplicate: [Android Studio 2.3. I got Failed to find Cmake. Install CMake and sync project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912919/android-studio-2-3-i-got-failed-to-find-cmake-install-cmake-and-sync-project)

Seems like you haven't installed cmake for android studio. Try the following:

1. Open Android studio to any project
2. Go to tools -> SDK Manager
3. Click the SDK Tools tab
4. Mark the checkbox for cmake on the list
5. Click apply, and follow the prompts while cmake is installed

This will install the proper cmake version for android studio to compile native code using the NDK. The install directory is ${HOME}/Android/SDK/cmake/