# CMake option not included SDK tools settings in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, sdk

I have been encountering a problem that says unable to sync files because `CMake` is not installed. In that case that `CMake` is necessary to sync, I'm unable to find it in:

```
Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools
```

[image]

Is there an alternate way to manually install CMake?

Comment: Please show your SDK Update Sites Tab screen shot

Answer (score 2):

> I'm unable to find it in `Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools`.

The point in here is that maybe you're using the Android Studio **32 bit** version and that's why it does not appear there ([Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569954/4409113)) so go to:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
```

And find `studio64.exe` then open the Android Studio by clicking on this file. [**`Cmake`**](https://cmake.org/download/#latest) should be visible-available to install with the SDK Manager on Android Studio after that.

- The other option will be installing the `Cmake` separately from it's website by installer or downloading the zip file of the `Cmake` and then the rest which mentioned [in here](https://cmake.org/install/).

---

It's available to download by SDK Manager on Android Studio v3.2 (**64 bit**) by the way:

[image]