# Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm trying to build a simple native app from Android Studio 3.0 on Windows 10. When I will try to build the app, I get the following error:

> "Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log xxx\Native\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_server_log.txt for additional information."

And the log contains:

> "CMAKE SERVER:
>   CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[
>   CMAKE SERVER: {"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}
>   CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]"

I have created the "CMakeLists.txt" as required in the official documenation..

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here, my problem was a manually compiled cmake. Installing cmake from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218241/unable-to-find-cmake-in-android-studio fixed it!

Comment: Seems like AndroidStudio won't work with CMake 3.10 for now. A possible source of the problem is the bump in cmake-server protocol version (to 1.1), but I can't find sources to Google's Adnroid Gradle Plugin to confirm that, and their error log is, at best, vague.

Comment: Spent a couple of hours trying to get that working, hoping to be able the compile for C++ 17. Downgrading CMake still did not work for whatever reason, though from 3.9.x it seems to pass the server version check. I've decided to keep using C++ 14 together with the CMake 3.6 binaries provided with the NDK and use a backporting of string_view since that's all I needed from C++ 17.

Answer (score 8):

Actually the issue is that Gradle is interpreting the debug output of the cmake-server as an error and fails. It happens with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` but it works correctly starting with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0`.

If for some reason (plugin, etc) you cannot update to 3.1.0, you can replace `cmake` with a python wrapper and filter the output by removing this exact output:

```
[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This worked for me.

Goto the SDK Manager --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools
--> CMake.

And install CMake from the SDK manager.
Just check the images if you don't get
what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check "Show Package Details" checkbox to see optional versions of every tool, and install/uninstall what fits to you. For me recplacing CMake 3.10.2 with CMake 3.6 did the work.

Comment: Uninstalling CMake 3.10.2 and installing 3.6.4111459 back did the trick for me either.

Comment: @RanSh Replace CMake 3.10.2 with CMake 3.6 worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got exact same error, even with the solution from kevvex, android studio reported same error.

I compared with another working windows 10 machine and found three differences:

1. CMake is 3.10xxx is not working on my machine, CMake 3.6.4111459 is on working machine
2. OpenCV-android-sdk version 2.4.7.2 is not working on my machine, OpenCV-android-sdk version 3.2.0 is on working machine
3. android-ndk/ndk-bundle 14.1.3816874 is not working on my machine, android-ndk/ndk-bundle r15c is on working machine (This one maybe optional)

Replaced these three items, the project is built successfully on my machine.

Comment: I replaced  CMake 3.6.4111459 with CMake 3.10***. Now its working fine.