# Error occurred while communicating with CMake server

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

Error occurred while communicating with CMake server

> Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log
>   C:\Users\Home\AndroidStudioProjects\SourceCode\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_server_log.txt
>   for additional information.

CMake Server Log:

> CMAKE SERVER:
>
> CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[
>
> CMAKE SERVER:
>   {"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}
>
> CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]

I can't make project with C++ libraries I would be appreciated if anybody can solve my problem.

Comment: Looks like same problem [Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393862/errorerror-occurred-while-communicating-with-cmake-server)