Android Studio installs CMake 3.18.1 but not 3.22.1
I am new to Android Studio and React Native development with Expo. I am trying to build the app by npx expo run:android. This is throwing below error in the build.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[x86_64]'.
> com.android.builder.sdk.InstallFailedException: Failed to install the following SDK components: 
      cmake;3.22.1 CMake 3.22.1
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

I am trying to use SDK Manager in Android Studio to install the CMake version 3.22.1 but it is giving below error.
enter image description here
I can successfully install version 3.18.1 however.
enter image description here
I am able to install 3.18.1 but 3.22.1 is not installing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218241/unable-to-find-cmake-in-android-studio
please check this

The screen shot shows the error test See IDE log for details have you checked that log file for the exact error message?
